# How to swap out packages that came from a PPA for Ubuntu provided versions?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

Embarrassingly, I reported [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8-desktop-session/+bug/1584635) that was in fact my own doing.

[image: Non-standard packages]

How can I safely remove the 11.0~git packages and replace them (if necessary) with Ubuntu provided mesa as suggested in the comment on the bug report?

I tried selecting them all for removal but they want to take out nearly every package in the system along with them.

I believe (although not certain) that they came from this repo I see in the list, disabled during the upgrade:

```
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/mesa
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: paulo-miguel-dias mesa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: paulo-miguel-dias mesa
```

The offending PPA seems to be http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/mesa/ubuntu

Comment: Look into `ppa-purge`.

Comment: You'll have to provide the details on what PPA repository you added, but you basically run ppa-purge ppa/name

Comment: Not sure where you got your drivers from. Are they from the oibaf PPA?

Comment: Must be this one: http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/mesa/ubuntu
I'll try that with ppa-purge, thanks.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers I see, let me update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install PPA Purge using `sudo apt install ppa-purge`. Then use `ppa-purge` to purge the offending PPA (padoka PPA) and restore the files that are found in the Ubuntu repositories by using `sudo ppa-purge ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/mesa`.

Comment: I'm not having much luck with that, updating the question with more info to see if it makes things clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers Let me know if that works.

Comment: Works a treat. Not sure why the same command didn't work yesterday but I'm up and running with Unity 8 on the desktop now. Thank you!